# ft_min_word_len set in local my.cnf?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

Is it possible to set ft_min_word_len for a certain user (such as by placing a my.cnf file in the user home dir with ft_min_word_len set)? The documentation says I need to restart the server after making this change, but a user does not have access to do that.

Answer (score 7):

I'm working with this now, so to add as a reference for anyone looking at this...

- You can use this query in a query
  browser or the MySQL prompt to show
  the state of ft_min_word_len:   "SHOW
  VARIABLES LIKE 'ft_min_word_len';"
- ft_min_word_len deafults to a value
  of '4' and is not by default listed
  in "my.cnf".   To change it's default
  value, add:  "ft_min_word_len = 3" to
  my.cnf under the [mysqld] section.
- After changing the value of
  ft_min_word_len, the server must be
  restarted.
- After changing the value of
  ft_min_word_len, any indexes you have
  must be rebuilt
- A fast way to rebuild an index is to
  use this query:  "REPAIR TABLE
  your_table_name QUICK;"   Note: 
  You're using the name of the table
  only, not the name of any indexes.
  If you have more than one index
  against the 'your_table_name' table,
  all of them will be re-built.

Comment: i follow the steps but the value for 'ft_min_word_len' does not change.
I also tried
set ft_min_word_len=3;
BUt gives
ERROR 1238 (HY000): Variable 'ft_min_word_len' is a read only variable

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not possible, because it changes how the fulltext indices are built. It takes effect at index generation, not (only) at query time.

FYI: Not only do you have to restart the server, you have to rebuild all your fulltext indices after changing it.